# Replace a string from template with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this template:

```
var temp = "<div class="${class}" id="loc" data-res="${res}"></div>";
```

and i would like to replace ${res} with an array, so I can later do something like that:

```
$('#loc').data('res');
```

I tried this:

```
var res = [["a","b"],["c","d"]];
var arr = { class: "bold", res: res};
var newtemp = rep(temp, arr);

function rep(temp, arr) 
        {
            return temp.replace(/\$\{([\w]+)\}/g, function(s1, s2) { 
                var s = arr[s2]; 
                if (typeof (s) != "undefined"){ 
                    return s; 
                } else { 
                    return s1; } 
            });
        }
```

But no way... for the ${res} sustitution and keep formated like an array. I would like this result:

```
<div class="bold" id="loc" data-res='[["a","b"],["c","d"]]'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the variable `s` is an array and then use `JSON.stringify()` to keep the array in the string format as you want.

But you `temp` variable has some issue. It contains double quotes inside double quotes. And in your expected result example, you use both double quotes and single quotes. So I suggest changing the `temp` variable to:

```js
var temp = `<div class="$class" id="loc" data-res='$res'></div>`;
```

And change the regex you're using a bit. The final `rep` function will be:

```js
function rep(temp, arr) {
    return temp.replace(/\$([\w]+)/g, function (s1, s2) {
        var s = arr[s2];
        if (typeof (s) != "undefined") {
            return Array.isArray(s) ? JSON.stringify(s) : s;
        } else {
            return s1;
        }
    });
}
```